# Facing error in logcat while lauching an app

Tags: android

java.lang.RuntimeExeptions:Unable to start activity ComponntInfo{com.securityExeption:PermitionDenial:writing com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider uri content://settings/system from pid=1895, uid=10056 requires android.permission.WRITE.SETTINGS

Comment: you are supposed to add the required permission..

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeExeptions:Unable to start activity ComponntInfo{com.securityExeption:PermitionDenial:writing com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider uri content://settings/system from pid=1895, uid=10056 requires android.permission.WRITE.SETTINGS .....this is showing in logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.RuntimeExeptions:Unable to start activity ComponntInfo{com.securityExeption:PermitionDenial:writing com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider uri content://settings/system from pid=1895, uid=10056 requires android.permission.WRITE.SETTINGS
```

add :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

to your project's manifest.xml file above **application** tag

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>I gave this permission.

Comment: ok, then add this permission under that permission like this :

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

Comment: I have done all this but after this it is showing some DEATH_NOTIFICATION in verbose of logcat.

Comment: Now,It is showing set stream Type in error field of Logcat..

Comment: add your activity code if you want more help